# In VSE i cant render any clip either as a still or as a video

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

[image]

Rendering was working just fine, and then all of a sudden i cant render a frame or a sequence from and clip loaded into VSE.

I have even uninstalled Blender and reinstalled but no joy

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: on a clip that has been brought into vse, i cant render a frame or a video from it

Comment: From your screen-grab, I can see that the Multiply property of the Color panel is keyframed. Could it be possible that this Multiply value is changed for the other frames?

Comment: yes i used the multiply to go very high for one frame everytime a new photo appeared to simulate a flash, this shouldnt be it tho as i have the same problem on every clip i bring in, the problem is only on a saved clip that i've re opened , every new clip i work on i can render a frame or a range of frames no problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

[image: output properties]

Did you check sequencer in the output properties under the post processing?

Comment: Hi, yes, both the compositing and sequencer boxes are ticked and dither is as on the photo on 1

Comment: every render of a frame from a video clip has a chequered square look , like it is an alpha channel